# jQuery .show('slide', { direction: 'right' }) doesn't work, but .show('slide') does

Tags: jquery, show, slide

I'm inserting a menu choice at the beginning of a top menu (ListItems) and using

```
$('#newMenuItem').show('slide');
```

successfully. However, I didn't like the way it slid in from the upper-left, so I changed it to

```
$('#newMenuItem').show('slide', { direction: 'right' });
```

Unfortunately, once I changed it I no longer get the new item at all. In fact, no code lower than the above line is getting executed anymore.

Is there an obvious reason why this wouldn't work? I'm using jquery-1.7.1 shipped with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI in your project? the effect you are trying  to use is part of jQuery UI and doesn't come bundled with vanilla jQuery.

Comment: Not jQuery UI, only jQuery. Is that the problem? (trying it now)

Comment: Yup, see my edit in the previous comment.

Comment: It does work now, but I can't mark this answered because it's a comment. Thanks @Mahn!

Comment: Np, mind if I post it as an answer so you can mark it?

Comment: I'd be glad if you did so!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The effect of sliding in a specific direction doesn't come bundled with vanilla jQuery, but it's instead part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/); including jQuery UI (in addition to jQuery) in your project should make it available. See also the documentation for the effect [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide).

Comment: And if we want only to have this effect, is there a minimal plugin that does this?

Comment: @OlivierPons
You can always build your own customized JQuery-UI with JQuery-UI builder, and it is officially available, try here [https://jqueryui.com/download/] and select the animations, effects or whatever you need and download.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `$('#newMenuItem').slideDown()`;