# How to make inputs slide in from right and left in jquery

Tags: jquery

What I am doing that when the page loads I want the email input to slide in from left and password input from right. But this doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $("#login_email").hide();
 $("#login_email").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
 $("#login_password").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input id="login_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" required autofocus>
<input id="login_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816525).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to hide both element (email and password) using `opacity:0;` in **CSS** then use **[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** function with current position.

**CSS**

```
#login_email {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  }
```

**JQuery**

```
 $("#login_email").animate({
        "opacity": "1",
        "left": "0px"
      }, 1000)
```

Check the working demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#login_email").animate({
    "opacity": "1",
    "left": "0px"
  }, 1000)

  $("#login_password").animate({
    "opacity": "1",
    "left": "200px"
  }, 1000)

});
```

```css
#login_email {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#login_password {
  opacity: 0;
  right: -100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="login_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" required autofocus>
<input id="login_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should simply set ***dir="rtl"*** property in your password element like

```
<input id="login_password" dir="rtl" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery UI as well.
Here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $("#login_email,#login_password").hide();
 $("#login_email").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
 $("#login_password").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <input id="login_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" required autofocus>
<input id="login_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this your requirement  .you just try this

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $("#login_email").hide();
    $("#login_password").hide();
 $("#login_email").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
 $("#login_password").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <input id="login_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" required autofocus>
<input id="login_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
```

Comment: Why you target twice your selectors? Can you do some methods concatenation instead?